# Android gradle test coverage exclude (pojo) classes?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, code-coverage, jacoco, android-instrumentation

I am running test coverage for android UI tests (androidTest) using 
`./gradlew createDevDebugCoverageReport`. The report however contains classes of which I don't need coverage, such as pojo classes and external libraries.

1) Is there a way to tell gradle to filter classes.

2) Can Jacoco create coverage report for UI tests? I have seen tutorials for jacoco but they only represent unit tests.